# HashSet and byte array-don't know how to get the data from that HashSet

Tags: c#, loops, arrays, hashset

I am trying to read that HashSet but I get only "System.Byte[]" as the output...

```
HashSet<byte[]> array2 = hash1Copy;


            foreach (var bullet in array2.OfType<byte[]>())
            {
                textBoxResults.Text += bullet + "\n"; 
            }
```

I know thats a beginner question, but  I need your help...

Comment: This is c#-thanks for your fast answer :)

Answer (score 0):

There are a few issues I think, one is of naming, you have something named array2, but it is not an array, it is a HashSet that contains a number of arrays. Naming it array2 may have confused you in thinking that what is returned is a single byte.

Because you have a HashSet of byte arrays your foreach gives you a single byte array in bullet each time it loops. A byte array doesn't cast to a useful string by default, you would have to make a string of it using System.Text.Encoding.whateverencoding.GetString.

If you wanted to print each single byte you need another foreach inside your current foreach.

Answer (score 0):

How can I print all duplicated entries ?

```
                int countForeach = 1;
            foreach (var bullet in arrayContainsHashes.OfType<byte[]>())
            {
                textBoxResults.Text += countForeach + ".:";
                foreach (var item in bullet)
                {
                    textBoxResults.Text += item.ToString();

                }
                countForeach++;
                textBoxResults.Text += "\n";
            }
```

Now, it guves me every hash